# slackr_setup() regression: Error in if (nrow(chan) == 0) { : argument is of length zero

Tags: r, slack-api

When I am trying to setup my slack environment variables with slackr_setup, I receive the following error:

`Error in if (nrow(chan) == 0) { : argument is of length zero`

I read that updating the slackr package with `devtools::install_github("mrkaye97/slackr")`
"would do the trick" but i still receive the same error and I am pretty confused. If anyone has a workaround that would be incredible!

Answer (score 0):

do you mind posting a `reprex` if possible that shows the issue? My guess is that this is fixed in the newest version of `slackr` (2.2.0), which you can install via CRAN or Github now, but if you try updating and keep getting this issue, I'd like to fix it!